# Why gives Weblogic server lambda expression error in deployment?

Tags: lambda, java-8, web-deployment, vaadin7, weblogic12c

I have a Vaadin project which i develop it via java8. I've been trying a deployment with Oracle weblogic 12c server. But I am getting an error like above when I try it via labmda expression. I removed Lambda expression an retried it. Weblogic has been deployed successfully.

How can i resolve this problem? Bytheway the server is remote.[image]

Comment: How can you deterministically that this is because of lambda, array out of bound exception doesn't indicate that issue is because of lambda, and when you are removing lambda code and it is getting deployed doesn't mean that issue is because of lambda, there could be other reasons. Can you put more information from WL error logs? Also, are you sure that you are using JRE 8 with your WL? If not then this is expected and you just need to use JRE8 for running WL.

Comment: I'm exactly sure JRE8 in weblogic.

Comment: Cool. Then please provide more error logs because from provided info it cannot be said that issue is lambda. As an aside, do this: deploy with lambda code --> get error in WL console, delete and undeploy application --> stop managed server (if you are deploying in a managed server) --> stop admin server --> start admin server --> start managed server --> deploy application .. And then see what happens

Comment: Thank you @hagrawal I'll do it, but the server is remote an I have no authentication for login as an admin. So i can not access log files. But I'm sure it's  about lambda. Because i changed maven version and also i got the same error.

Comment: So, what are results? Your problem solved?

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: Ok. Please provide more details and error logs.

Comment: Hi @hagrawal, I have removed all lambda expressions in my project, and now it works clearly. I am definitly serious! I dont know that is an issue!

Comment: Try to put this code in any class and see what happens - `private static String getMyString()
 {
    return "Hello";
 }

 private void someMethod()
 {
    java.util.function.Supplier<String> mySupplier = <<your_class_name_where_you_are_putting_this_method>>::getMyString;
    java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(mySupplier); // errors
 }`

Comment: My compiler could not resolve this line ( <<MainUI.class >>::getMyString;)

Comment: If your class name is `MainUI` then have it like this `MainUI::getMyString` (don't put ".class", in case if you are putting it)

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation to that. When I ran the code made by @hagrawal, WL return the same error. Any tips?

Comment: I removed weblogicserver 12.1.2 and installed newest version of weblogic server 12.2.1 There is no any problem. I think, it's about weblogic server versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a specific solution, but I removed weblogicserver 12.1.2 and installed newest version of weblogic server 12.2.1 There is no any problem. I think, it's about weblogic server versions.

Comment: Of course it helped. Weblogic supports java 1.8 since 12.1.3 only

Comment: @stasal We have 12.1.3 but it doesn't actually work. It seems to only work on 12.2 :(

Comment: Do you use Java8 with lambda? it may occure lambda?